# API Gateway Redirect 302

Tags: api, redirect, amazon-web-services, gateway

I've got a service I'm proxying with gateway. A GET request to / will return a 302 with a Location header. The problem is the value of the Location header which I'm referencing in "integration.response.header.Location" is /login.

What this ends up doing is breaking my proxy by removing the stageName from the AWS provided URL for the API.

Instead of "{AWS_URL}/local/login", the redirect is going to "{AWS_URL}/login" which causes a 403 Forbidden from API Gateway.

If I manually modify the header mapping expression to use 'local/login' all works fine, but, the above should work, no?

Is there some hackery to maybe concat values into a header mapping expression?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moved to AWS Forums as it may be more appropriate - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228457